# how to properly export my character from blender to mixamo to apply animation

Tags: rigging, armature

I downloaded a character from mixamo and then in blender edit some changes in character but when i export the character in FBX and try to upload the character on mixamo it won't let me upload
[image: Saying unable to map your existing skeleton]

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong
this is my character
[image]

I added the exo suit is it because of that?

Comment: If you didn't edit the skeleton the animations will be compatible with the original model. So there is no reason to upload back to miaxamo, just download the animations what you need.

Comment: i don't want any skeleton i want to auto rig on mixamo

Comment: I see. Probably it can't recognise the topology. Try to assign the vertex groups in Edit Mode or Weightpaint Mode.

Answer (score 1):

solved it ! it turns out I had too many vertices in my model by decimating the mesh it got uploaded and perfectly rigged
Go to edit mode
**Mesh->cleanUp->Decimate Geometry**
decrease the ratio to reduce mesh size